# Relationship between Functor, Applicative Functor, and Monad

Tags: haskell

When reading up on type classes I have seen that the relationship between Functors, Applicative Functors, and Monads is that of strictly increasing power. Functors are types that can be mapped over. Applicative Functors can do the same things with *certain* effects. Monads the same with *possibly unrestrictive* effects. Moreover:

```
Every Monad is an Applicative Functor
Every Applicative Functor is a Functor
```

The definition of the Applicative Functor shows this clearly with:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure  :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But the definition of Monad is:

```
class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>)   :: m a -> m b -> m b
  m >> n = m >>= \_ -> n
  fail   :: String -> m a
```

According to Brent Yorgey's great [typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Monad) that an alternative definition of monad could be:

```
class Applicative m => Monad' m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

which is obviously simpler *and* would cement that Functor < Applicative Functor < Monad. So why isn't this the definition? I know applicative functors are new, but according to the [2010 Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) page 80, this hasn't changed. Why is this?

Comment: Not sure if this would be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: "Monads the same with unrestrictive effects." Where did you get that idea?

Comment: I am of course making the mistake of putting an equal sign between Monads and IO. What would be more correct to say?

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist: Perhaps "dependent" would be a better word. The main difference between Applicative and Monad is the types of `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and `(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`, i.e. the `m` part of the result can depend on the `a` from the input, while for an applicative the `f` part of the result must be the same independent of the value of the `a` input.

Comment: `class Applicative m => Monad'' m where join :: m (m a) -> m a` is another possible minimal complete definition. (also noted in typeclassopedia)

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist: Here's an explanation of what Monad gives you over Applicative that I like: Applicative forces the structure of the computation to be *static*, whereas Monad allows it to be *dynamic*, depending on the results of other computations.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'd like to add that `Applicative` is now indeed a superclass of `Monad`. This happened quite a few years ago, but oh well..
https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/applicative_monad.md

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Everyone wants to see Applicative become a superclass of Monad, but it would break so much code (if `return` is eliminated, every current Monad instance becomes invalid) that everyone wants to hold off until we can extend the language in such a way that avoids breaking the code ([see here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances) for one prominent proposal).

Haskell 2010 was a conservative, incremental improvement in general, standardising only a few uncontroversial extensions and breaking compatibility in [one area](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FixityResolution) to bring the standard in line with every existing implementation. Indeed, Haskell 2010's libraries don't even include Applicative — less of what people have come to expect from [the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) is standardised than you might expect.

Hopefully we'll see the situation improve soon, but thankfully it's usually only a mild inconvenience (having to write `liftM` instead of `fmap` in generic code, etc.).

Comment: Not *everyone* wants `Applicative` to become a superclass of `Monad`

Answer (score 8):

Changing the definition of Monad at this point, would have broken a lot of existing code (any piece of code that defines a Monad instance) to be worthwhile.

Breaking backwards-compatibility like that is only worthwhile if there is a large practical benefit to the change. In this case the benefit is not that big (and mostly theoretical anyway) and wouldn't justify that amount of breakage.

Comment: In what way do you mean that it would break compatibility? 'Applicative m => Monad m' probably breaks certain existing code. But the fix should be easy and Haskell 2010 already is not entirely backwards compatible.

Comment: Haskell 2010 is entirely backwards compatible with real implementations of Haskell 98, I believe; the breaking change in syntax was something that every compiler already implemented the way Haskell 2010 mandates.

Comment: Everyone wants to see Applicative become a superclass of Monad, but it would break so much code that everyone wants to hold off until we can extend the language in such a way that avoids breaking the code. [See here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances) for one prominent proposal.

Comment: @ehird Thanks, it should almost be an answer though!

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist: I couldn't resist expanding it into an answer :)